# Legend without colors

Tags: legending, charts

I am doing a simple barchart plot:

```
data = {{3, 3, 1}, {2, 4, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 1}};

BarChart[data,
 Frame -> True,
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 28, FontFamily -> "Arial", Black},
 BarSpacing -> {0.1, 2},
 PlotRange -> {All, {-4.5, 6}},
 PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 0.5}, 0},
 AspectRatio -> 0.4,
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[3]],
 ChartLegends -> 
  Placed[SwatchLegend[{Style["A", 23], Style["B", 23], 
     Style["C", 23]}, LegendMarkerSize -> 20, 
    LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, Background -> GrayLevel[0.95], 
        FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]] &), 
    LegendLayout -> "Row"], Below],
 PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

However, I do not get the colors in the legend. Any clue is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: In v.13.2, the colours appear just fine. Maybe a kernel issue? Does it persist restarting mathematica and evaluating the above code?

Comment: No issues with color while using v12.2.0 on Win7-x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code runs with no issues on v.13.2.1, so it is either a version or Kernel issue. In case the problem persists on a fresh start of MMA, then perhaps try by having explicit colours used:

```
data = {{3, 3, 1}, {2, 4, 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {3, 4, 1}};
cols = System`PlotThemeDump`$ThemeDefaultGradient[[;; ;; 2]];
BarChart[data, Frame -> True, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 28, FontFamily -> "Arial", Black}, 
 BarSpacing -> {0.1, 2}, PlotRange -> {All, {-4.5, 6}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{0, 0.5}, 0}, AspectRatio -> 0.4, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[3]], 
 ChartLegends -> 
  Placed[SwatchLegend[
    cols, {Style["A", 23], Style["B", 23], Style["C", 23]}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> 20, 
    LegendFunction -> (Framed[#, Background -> GrayLevel[0.95], 
        FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick]] &), 
    LegendLayout -> "Row"], Below], PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Works on 13.2.1 also.

Comment: this is very annoying now. I restarted the computer. I have all the updates but still I do not have the colors in the legend. I am running version 12.0.0.0. At least I have a workaround by @Alex.